# Using ant-design-vue Notification

Tags: vue.js, antd

I cannot get ant-design-vue Notification (or Message) to work in my project, which I created with vue-cli 3. I am using the examples from https://vue.ant.design/components/notification/ but the Notifications do not appear.

After doing some research on the ant-design-vue issues on GitHub, I believe this may be due to a defect in ant-design-vue itself. It does not appear to support Notification messages when a global render function is called, as is created by vue-cli 3, like this:

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I think that this is a defect because of this issue:

https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/issues/554

I believe that ant-design-vue Notification would work if I used this style to create my Vue object:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

However, when I change my main.js to use this second style of creating the Vue component, nothing renders in my SPA. So I'm stuck - I can't use ant-design-vue Notification because I don't think it works with render: h => h(App), nor can I switch the way I create the Vue app to the way I think works with Notification.

Help is appreciated - I'm new to Javascript, Vue, and Ant Design.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is here:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-ant-design-vue-notification/66265/8